# DEBUG only one function (or module), RUN rest of the program in Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I will try to explain my question on simple example program (my problem is much more complex because my program is much more complex).

Lets suppose i have a program that has 2 lines, making 2 functions:

```
data = long_one()  #takes 2 hours in DEBUG mode, 15min in RUN mode
short_one(data)    #i want to DEBUG this one
```

Lets also say that it is very difficult to prepare the `data` variable and the only way to obtain it is by running the function long_one().

Is there a way to RUN `long_one()` and DEBUG `short_one()` in Pycharm?
In other words is there a way to perform either:

1. DEBUG with specification that `long_one()` should be processed in RUN mode
2. or RUN with specification that `short_one()` should be debugged?

Comment: In the python console there's a button for attach debugger.  That's the one I usually use.  I haven't tried this, but maybe you can in run/edit configurations tag the "Show command line afterwards" and then use tools/attach_to_process.  If you attach a debugger you will have to import short_one

Comment: @Asagen Well, although it is not an answer to my question, it is defenitely resolving my problem!  There is one inconvenience that you must know when to start debugging, but i have a workaround (description in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Asagen has proposed:

1. attached debugger to python console.
2. started my script in RUN mode
3. while script was running I did `Tools/Attach to Process` and have chosen my process.

The debugger has started from the moment i did this and stopped on first breakpoint it encountered.

---

There was one inconvenience - I had to know when to start debugging (in which moment to attach debugger to process). I propose a workaround:

1. Add to code an infininte loop in place you want to start debugging (see below):

---

```
data = long_one()  # takes 2 hours in DEBUG mode, 15min in RUN mode
infinite_loop = True
print "OK man, it is the time to start debugging!"
while infinite_loop:
    time.sleep(0.2)   # add breakpoint here
short_one(data)    #i want to DEBUG this one
```

---

2. Add a breakpoint inside the while loop
3. While running process, when you see in console the printed text "OK man, it is the time to start debugging!", attach debugger to process.
4. Next when it stops in the infinite loop, evaluate code fragment `infinite_loop = False`, so you leave the loop

It is it, you are now in DEBUG mode after running whole code before,

If you want to get back to RUN mode, just stop debugger. It is possible to switch between RUN and DEBUG as many times and in any places you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def do_the_thing_for_debug():
    print('doing the debug version')

def do_the_thing():
    print('doing the release version')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Detecting if you're in the PyCharm debugger or not
    WARNING: This is a hacky & there is probably a better 
             way of doing this by looking at other items in the
             global() namespace or environment for things that
             begin with PyCharm and stuff.
             Also, this could break in future versions of PyCharm!
    If you put a breakpoint HERE and look at the callstack you will 
    see the entry point is in 'pydevd.py'
    In debug mode, it copies off sys.argv: "sys.original_argv = sys.argv[:]"
    We abuse this knowledge to test for the PyCharm debugger.
    """
    if hasattr(sys, 'original_argv'):
        do_the_thing = do_the_thing_for_debug

    do_the_thing()
```

Output from PyCharm when I "run" it

```
doing the release version
```

Output from PyCharm when I "debug" it

```
doing the debug version
```

Comment: As the code states it is "Detecting if you're in the PyCharm debugger or not". My question was how to "mix" DEBUG and RUN modes.